# CSS : Button text moves on click

Tags: html, css

```css
 .btn_style{
   border: none;
   outline: 0;
   background: #edf1f2;
   border-radius: 2px;
   width: 90px;
   height: 30px;
}
.btn_style:focus{
   border: thin #c7d3d6 solid;
   width: 90px;
   height: 30px;
   outline: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn_style">Medium</button>
```

When I click on button then the text is moving slightly.

Any help would be great.

Thank you.

Comment: unrelated to the question, but unless is absolutely necessary or it's handled via JS I would suggest to NOT remove the outline on :focus. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```css
.btn_style{
            border: none;
            outline: 0;
            background: #edf1f2;
            border-radius: 2px;
            width: 90px;
            height: 30px;
            padding:0;
            margin:0;
             
          }

          .btn_style:focus{
            border: thin #c7d3d6 solid;
            width: 90px;
            height: 30px;
            outline: 0 !important;
          }
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn_style">Medium</button>
```

Add `padding:0` and `margin:0` to `.btn_style`. this will solve your issue.

Hope this helps.

Comment: glad to help you... :)

Comment: accepting you answer in 10 minutes due to stackoverflow time limit.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code for your button

```
.btn_style {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
```

```css
.btn_style {
    border: none;
    outline: 0;
    background: #edf1f2;
    border-radius: 2px;
    width: 90px;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

.btn_style:focus {
    border: thin #c7d3d6 solid;
    width: 90px;
    height: 30px;
    outline: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn_style">Medium</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

The default user agent styles vary for `button` elements across browsers.
Not reproducible on Chrome 55 though.

To be safe always add `padding: 0; margin: 0` to your `button` elements.

Comment: But what if you want padding and margin?